# SQL Select where based on excel column

Tags: sql

I think what I'm doing would just about have to have a standardized solution. To keep it simple: I have a SQL database with a Location(string) and Property Number column. Example

```
LOCATION | PROP_NUM
-------------------
SW U.S.  |  1
SW U.S.  |  2
SW U.S.  |  3
NE U.S.  |  4
SE U.S.  |  5
```

However, It has been decided that SW U.S. should be broken out into states. So for argument sake, prop 1 and 3 needs to go to Texas, Prop 2 needs to go to Arizona. There is an excel file that has documented all of these (100k +). I'm not very strong in SQL, my initial thought is to write a console app, read the excel file, and create a where in statement to change using a string builder. Alternatively, if that is too slow, manually run through each record and compare against the excel.

If so, what? Is it possible to set up a script to say "Where in EXCEL_Column C"

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you described is a detail less we will allow to discern the way of acting in the solution: in what environment are you working?
For example, if you're working in SQL SERVER  is very simple by using the LINKED SERVER through which you log in to your EXCEL sheet and you can interrogate him or with a four-level syntax or openquery as if it were a normal database.

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQL SERVER

Comment: Then you can use linked server yo link your excel file and query it. Open the enterprise manager and go to the section linked server. then link your spreedsheet, then try some query with four level syntax or open query. If you have problems write me. Good luck!